# How can I express the idea of CSS floats to ordinary people?

Tags: terminology, wording

Let me explain what CSS floats are:

When there is no float, text and image looks like this:

[image]

When the image is floated left (I don't know whether "floated left" is the right term for this. In CSS `img { float: left; }` is what I mean.)

[image]

When the image is floated right: `img { float: right; }`

[image]

So basically the idea is, that when a float is present, the text always wraps around the image.

In my iOS app, users can write a document and add an image to it. I want to give the above 3 options to the users. Users can choose one of the above options and the images and texts in the document will behave accordingly.

What I am stuck on is how to word these options. Since I target normal, ordinary people, I don't expect them to know CSS floats. So I must express these three options in a colloquial way. What I had in mind is too verbose, I think:

- Text doesn't wrap image
- Text wraps image, image on the left
- Text wraps image, image on the right

I don't think people will be bothered to read through that long text. I need a more concise expression. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct me if i am wrong please, I think most people who use Microsoft Word has an idea what exactly you would like to communicate the terminology. You can use below term (with icon if possible will give the user a quick idea about it)

Text Wrapping:

- In line with text
- Left
- Right

Comment: In print we used to call this 'Runaround'

Comment: Word also adds an image/icon to clarify too.